# Label formatting tag escape characters in ArcGIS Pro with VB?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

I have catch basins that I've joined to a table of inspection data.
I want to label the catch basin ID in bold followed by the inspection results each on new lines below unbolded.

It appears to fail when the test results table has a "<" in it as shown below on the left.  it works fine for the one on the right.

[image]

Is there an escape character I can use somewhere (either in my label expression or in the table, itself) that will correct the formatting in those cases?

this is the label expression I have now:

```
"<BOL><UND>" & [L1Storm_Inlets.FACILITYID] & "</UND></BOL>"&vbnewline&"Chlorine: "&[FullComparison.Chlorine]&vbnewline&"Temperature (F): "&[FullComparison.Temperature]&vbnewline&"E-coli (cfu/100ml): "&[FullComparison.E_coli]&vbnewline&"Enterococci (cfu/100ml): "&[FullComparison.Enterococci]&vbnewline&"Surfactants (mg/l): "&[FullComparison.Surfactants]&vbnewline&"Ammonia-Nit. (mg/l): "&[FullComparison.Ammonia_Nit]
```

I forget the number, but it's the most recent release of ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use Pro but according to the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm), it appears that this works the same way in Pro that it did in ArcMap. The less-than sign and the ampersand are both special characters and they will break your formatting unless you use the escape codes, which are `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively.

It's probably not a good idea to replace the < symbol in your analytical results with that code just for labeling purposes, so I'd add a field to your attribute table just for label text if you can.

Comment: Excellent point to add a new field to label from rather than messing with the actual numbers our inspectors logged.  Thanks!